# Checking existence of a input argument to a Matlab function

Tags: matlab, function

I'm trying to check the input of a Matlab function to see whether the user has forgotten about it or not (which is easy to do in this case).

If the user has not supplied `number_obs` then I want to pause the program and wait for the user to input this information.

Some other StackOverflow posts seem to suggest using `~exist` however this doesn't seem to work. Can anybody suggest what I'm doing wrong here?

```
function output=test(number_obs) 
if ~exist('number_obs'),
    number_obs=input('How many observations do you have in your experiments?')
end
```

The Python equivalent would be something like:

```
def test(number_obs):
    if nummber_obs != None:
        output=raw_input('How many observations do you have in your experiments? :')
    return output
```

Comment: Your Python code does not work correctly, as the `number_obs` does not have a default value.

Comment: What is not working? Asking for an input when you already passed it or the opposite case?

Comment: What do you mean by "this doesn't seem to work"? The MATLAB version works flawlessly.

Comment: Your code works fine for me, MATLAB R2014b

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with [nargin](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nargin.html)

```
function output=test(number_obs) 
if nargin<1
    number_obs=input('How many observations do you have in your experiments?')
end
```

Answer (score 2):

(Edited to correct the truth)  It may not matter here, but to be on the safe side, you should always specify the type of object you're checking. In your case, its a 'var', so

```
if ~exist('number_obs','var'),
```

Thanks to dasdingonesin for pointing this out.

Comment: It doesn't need to. The second argument is optional (see http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/exist.html).

Comment: @dasdingonesin I plead guilty to not reading up-to-date help files.